# Using localStorage to keep css style in react after page reload

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to use localStorage to store a css style `:focus` for my elements. Currently when I click on component in my Dropdown it toggles green color, but when I click outside of it or I reload page, it disappears. Check the screenshot below.

How I can implement here localStorage to save `:focus` after page reload or maybe there is even better way of doing that which I don't know?

**My Menu**

```
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
    let companyElements = props.state.companies.map(c => (
        <DropdownItem key={c.id} name={c.name} owner={c.owner} id={c.id} /> ));
return (
    <div className="dropdown">
        {companyElements}
    </div>
);

}
```

**My Item**

```
const NavItem = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="#" className="icon-button"
                   onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                    {props.state.companies[0].name}
                </a>
                {open && props.children}
            </li>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Style**

```
.menu-item:focus{
    background-color: green;
}
```

[image: Dropdown component]

Comment: local storage is not ideal for this purpose. You should update your page url to determine the selected menu. update your url query param like `selected-menu=some%20x` then in your `map` add an active class to selected-menu. This way even if you share the page url with someone else, he'll get the menu item highlighted.

Comment: @AmirSaleem Hey Amir! Thanks for response, can you provide an example for it? A little bit don't understand selected-menu part of your comment, if it's possible

Comment: something like this `https://website.com/path?selected-menu=some%20x`